# Set $TemplateUrl within controller (angular-new-router in angular 1.4)

Tags: angularjs, angular-new-router

Based on this video@ng-vegas: [New Angular Router: Bridging the Gap Between 1.x and 2](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=DGT3Htcqygk), the presenter said totally 3 ways to define controller and template in new router. 3rd one(starting at 8:40) allow us to define custom template url inside a controller like below:

```
ArticleController.$templateUrl = 'whatever.html';
ArticleController() {...}
```

However, I tried, but with no luck. So has the 3rd way disappeared or there is another grammar?

Comment: Have you setted the Component Mapper Config, like the video shown?

Comment: I know that, but if doing that way, all the templates have to follow certain unified pattern which may be not existed.